# Django Signals not creating profile after user registration

Tags: python, django, user-profile

I want the profile to be created once the user registration is complete but I am having to create a profile separate for the existing user.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from main.models import Membership
# Create your models here.

    class Profile(models.Model):
        membership = models.OneToOneField(
            Membership, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="membership", default="null")
        
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
            
        couple_with = models.OneToOneField(
            User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="couple_with", blank=True, null=True)
    
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        maiden_name = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank="")
        street_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        )
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default="Select")
        date_of_birth = models.DateField( blank=True, null=True)
        address2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        zip = models.CharField(max_length=5)
        country_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        graduate_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
        
        def __str__(self):     
            return(self.first_name + " " + self.last_name) 
    
        @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
        def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
            user = instance
            print(user)
            if created:
                profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
                profile.save()
```

This is what my views.py looks like. I don't know where am I slipping. It is able to create the user once registered but the profile is never created and Admin has to create the profile manually.

```
def register_account(request):
    # check if the user is already logged in
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("main:home")

    # if not logged in
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)

            # check if the form is valid
            if form.is_valid():
                user = form.save(commit=False)

                duplicate = False
                nonWarhawks = False
                # for u in users:
                #     if user.email == u.email:
                #         error_message = "Email Already Exists"
                #         duplicate = True
                #         break
                if User.objects.filter(email=user.email).exists():
                    duplicate = True

                # duplicate check
                if duplicate:
                    return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {"error_message": "Email Already Exists", "form": form})

                user.is_active = False

                user.save()

                # create profile
                user.refresh_from_db()

                user.profile.copule_with = None
                user.profile.first_name = request.POST.get("first_name")
                user.profile.last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
                user.profile.maiden_name = request.POST.get("maiden_name")
                user.profile.street_address = request.POST.get("street_address")
                user.profile.city = request.POST.get("city")
                user.profile.zip = request.POST.get("zipcode")
                user.profile.country_name = request.POST.get("country_name")
                user.profile.graduate_year = request.POST.get("graduate_year")

                print(user.profile.first_name)
                user.profile.save()

                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
                message = render_to_string('accounts/acc_active_email.html', {
                    'user': user,
                    'domain': current_site.domain,
                    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
                    'protocol': 'http'
                })
                to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                email = EmailMessage(
                    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
                )
                email.send()

                print("Successfully sent email using the sendgrid api")
                return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
                # return redirect("daily:home")
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, 'accounts/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please *don't* use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this outside your Profile class.

```
 def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
     if kwargs['created']:
         user_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


 post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have included your @receiver signal inside your profile class. A signal based method isn't actually part of the class it involves. Remove the indentation so it is on the same level as your class Profile declaration